# If no items in Array, show No Data Label (WatchKit)

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, watchkit

I'm using `Parse` to pull in data into a simple `Table View`.  When there is no data I show a `label` via this:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    NSInteger numOfSections = 0;
    if ([self.stringArray count] > 0)
    {
        self.tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleSingleLine;
        numOfSections                 = 1;
        self.tableView.backgroundView = nil;
    }
    else
    {
        UILabel *noDataLabel         = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.tableView.bounds.size.width, self.tableView.bounds.size.height)];
        noDataLabel.text             = @"No data available";
        noDataLabel.textColor        = [UIColor blackColor];
        noDataLabel.textAlignment    = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
        self.tableView.backgroundView = noDataLabel;
        self.tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;
    }

    return numOfSections;
}
```

**I can't figure out how to do the same thing in `WatchKit` since `Table View`s work a bit different.  But I'm just showing the same data in the `iPhone` view as the `Watch` view.**

[image]

Here is what I have in my `WatchKit` `InterfaceController.m`.  I need to add a similar logic to what I do in the `TableViewController.m` for adding a "No Data" label if there's no data, any ideas how that would work in `WatchKit`?

```
- (void)willActivate {
    // This method is called when watch view controller is about to be visible to user
    [super willActivate];

    [self.myTable setNumberOfRows:[self.data count] withRowType:@"myRows"];

    for (NSInteger index = 0; index < [self.data count]; index++) {
        NSString *title = [self.data objectAtIndex:index];
        MyRowController *controller = [self.myTable rowControllerAtIndex:index];
        [controller.myLabel setText:title];
        NSLog(@"Title: %@", title);
    }

    for (NSInteger index = 0; index < [self.dataDate count]; index++) {
        NSString *titleDate = [self.dataDate objectAtIndex:index];
        MyRowController *controller = [self.myTable rowControllerAtIndex:index];
        [controller.myLabel2 setText:titleDate];
        NSLog(@"TitleDate: %@", titleDate);
    }

}
```

**EDIT:** Added per Skylar Lauren answer.  Still getting a blank WatchKit scene with no label though.

```
if ([self.data count] > 0)
{
    UILabel *noDataAvailableLabel         = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(15, 15, 15, 15)];

    noDataAvailableLabel.hidden = YES;
    self.myTable.hidden = NO;

    [self.myTable setNumberOfRows:[self.data count] withRowType:@"myRows"];

    for (NSInteger index = 0; index < [self.data count]; index++) {
        NSString *title = [self.data objectAtIndex:index];
        MyRowController *controller = [self.myTable rowControllerAtIndex:index];
        [controller.myLabel setText:title];
        NSLog(@"Title: %@", title);
    }

    for (NSInteger index = 0; index < [self.dataDate count]; index++) {
        NSString *titleDate = [self.dataDate objectAtIndex:index];
        MyRowController *controller = [self.myTable rowControllerAtIndex:index];
        [controller.myLabel2 setText:titleDate];
        NSLog(@"TitleDate: %@", titleDate);
    }

}
else
{
    UILabel *noDataAvailableLabel         = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(15, 15, 15, 15)];
    self.myTable.hidden = YES;
    noDataAvailableLabel.hidden = NO;
    noDataAvailableLabel.text             = @"No data available";
    noDataAvailableLabel.textColor        = [UIColor blackColor];
    noDataAvailableLabel.textAlignment    = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
}
```

Comment: you create the label in your storyboard like you created your table and then make an outlet to that label. Hopefully that makes sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest of solutions would be to add a label to your WatchKit view in your storyboard called noDataAvailableLabel and set the text to "No data available" and just either hide the myTable or the noDataAvailableLabel.

```
if ([self.data count] > 0])
{
    self.noDataAvailableLabel.hidden = YES;
    self.myTable.hidden = NO;

    [self.myTable setNumberOfRows:[self.data count] withRowType:@"myRows"];

    for (NSInteger index = 0; index < [self.data count]; index++) {
        NSString *title = [self.data objectAtIndex:index];
        MyRowController *controller = [self.myTable rowControllerAtIndex:index];
        [controller.myLabel setText:title];
        NSLog(@"Title: %@", title);
    }

    for (NSInteger index = 0; index < [self.dataDate count]; index++) {
        NSString *titleDate = [self.dataDate objectAtIndex:index];
        MyRowController *controller = [self.myTable rowControllerAtIndex:index];
        [controller.myLabel2 setText:titleDate];
        NSLog(@"TitleDate: %@", titleDate);
    }

}
else
{
    self.myTable.hidden = YES;
    self.noDataAvailableLabel.hidden = NO;
}
```

The other option is to add a new row type called noData and use that instead of myRows.

```
if ([self.data count] > 0])
{

    [self.myTable setNumberOfRows:[self.data count] withRowType:@"myRows"];

    for (NSInteger index = 0; index < [self.data count]; index++) {
        NSString *title = [self.data objectAtIndex:index];
        MyRowController *controller = [self.myTable rowControllerAtIndex:index];
        [controller.myLabel setText:title];
        NSLog(@"Title: %@", title);
    }

    for (NSInteger index = 0; index < [self.dataDate count]; index++) {
        NSString *titleDate = [self.dataDate objectAtIndex:index];
        MyRowController *controller = [self.myTable rowControllerAtIndex:index];
        [controller.myLabel2 setText:titleDate];
        NSLog(@"TitleDate: %@", titleDate);
    }

}
else
{
     [self.myTable setNumberOfRows:1 withRowType:@"noData"];
}
```

Comment: That makes sense, but I'm still getting a blank WatchKit scene with no label.  I added the code I'm using to my question, to show you what I'm using per your suggestion.  See anything there that looks like its missing/needed?

Comment: You add the label in the watchkit storyboard like your table with an outlet. Not create one on the fly.

Comment: I did that, and it showed up, but what's happening now is that it shows up even if there is data.  So it shows up even though the code it runs thru is `noDataAvailableLabel.hidden = YES;`, any ideas?

Comment: I would check to make sure you are calling that on the outlet instead of the UIlabel you created in code. I would also try logging out the outlet to make sure the connection is correct.

Comment: Awesome. Good luck with your app.